# How to integrate existing ASP.NET app into existing website in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

I have an existing website, built in Visual Studio 2010, that I would like to integrate with a web application I wrote in ASP.NET/C# (also in VS2010). When I try to move the pages to the website (just dragging and dropping), the MyPage.aspx.designer.cs file doesn't stay in the 'group' of files. (.aspx, .aspx.cs)

For reference, (if it matters), my application is an Online Application for my company, where people can apply online.

Any help is appreciated!!

-E

[Update]: This is the error I get when trying to view an integrated page in the browser:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TheEnd.aspx.cs"   Inherits="ApplicantEntry.TheEnd" %>

Line 2: 

Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your website to be a "Web Application" to achieve what you're wanting to here. Right click on the site and select "Convert to Web Application". That should do the trick.

Alternatively, if you *must* keep your website non-Web Application, then you can just delete the designer file, you don't need it with a Website. But it's recommended practice now to work with Web Applications.

Comment: My boss is a little wary of that since the site we're trying to integrate this with is live. Would that make any major changes that would jeopardize the integrity of the existing website?

Comment: Just saw that you edited your post. Would deleting the designer file lose formats?

Comment: Not really, but obviously what I'd do first is make a complete backup of the website in an external folder (out of Source Control), then convert that to a Web Application and fully test run it. It's recommended these days to work with a Web App. Alternatively, you just don't need the .designer file, that's the quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Nope, the designer file simply tells the .aspx page which controls you have on your page and their designated namespaces. A Website does not require this complexity, whereas a Web Application does.

Comment: Just tried that and when we tried to view it in the browser, we got this error in the first 3 lines of code:

    Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TheEnd.aspx.cs" Inherits="ApplicantEntry.TheEnd" %>

Line 2: 

Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: Also, since a web application requires the .designer files, how can we integrate it into a website without those very files?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error for me? Make sure you're clicking on the Default.aspx and pressing F5 to run your project under IIS Express for debug.

Comment: Aha! Glad you asked. The designer file gets compiled into the .DLL for the Web Application (thus the Application part :)), a Website does not require DLL compilation, whereas a Web Application does.

Comment: The error will be based around the site not being built (DLL compiled) - what happens when you do the F5 compile?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17303/discussion-between-hernameisellie-and-thedixon)